# PHPで作成した問い合わせフォームからメールが送信できない

Tags: php, html

PHPの初心者ですが、送信ボタンを押してもgmailの方に届きません。迷惑メールの方も確認しましたがなかったです。
dockerを使ってxserverにあげています。どこが原因でメールが送れないのでしょうか？
回答お待ちしております。

**index.php**

```html
<form action="contact.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-content pt-5">
        <div class="form-left ">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name
                " placeholder="名前">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-5">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email
                " placeholder="メールアドレス">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message
                " placeholder="お問い合わせ" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="上記の内容で送信する" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit text-center" id="button"></p>
</form>
```

**contact.php**

```php
<?php
echo 'hello';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $emailFrom = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $mailTo = "valance46matafall@gmail.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt ="You have received an e-mail from " .$name.".\n\n".$message;

    mail($mailTo, $txt , $headers);
    header("location: contact.php?mailsend");        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

contact.php側で

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

という条件分岐がありますが、index.php側の送信フォームにあるsubmitボタンは

```
<input type="submit" value="上記の内容で送信する" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit text-center" id="button">
```

となっており、name属性がありません。このため、`$_POST['submit']`が常にセットされていない状態だからでしょう。なので

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="上記の内容で送信する" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit text-center" id="button">
```

としてやれば良いです。

Comment: 無事メールが送信されました。わかりやすい解説ありがとうございます。助かりました。